# WebBrowser control in ASP doesn't work when published

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an ASP page with a WebBrowser control that goes on a website, logs into that website and gets redirected to one of my pages that updates the database. When I run it on my machine everything works fine, but when I publish my website, code is executing but the database is not updated (I can see the Thread doing the sleep). I'm not sure if a redirection is done though. Here is the code :

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim thread As New Thread(Sub()
                                 Using browser As New WebBrowser()
                                     browser.AllowNavigation = True
                                     browser.Navigate("https://www.website.com?redirect_uri=http://mywebsite.com/myPage.aspx")
                                     AddHandler browser.DocumentCompleted, New WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf DocumentCompleted)
                                     While browser.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
                                         System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
                                     End While
                                 End Using
                             End Sub)
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
    thread.Start()
    thread.Join()
End Sub
Private Sub DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
        Dim browser As WebBrowser = TryCast(sender, WebBrowser)
    browser.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("value", "email@hotmail.com")
    browser.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", "password")
    browser.Document.All.GetElementsByName("authorize").Item(0).InvokeMember("click")
    Thread.Sleep(6000)
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the http request for the page is finished, your thread is killed.

Don't use a WebBrowser control for this. Use the System.Net.WebClient object, or the System.Net.HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse objects instead.

Comment: The reason i'm using a WebBrowser is because it makes the login easy. I didn't have success with WebRequest/Repsonse. Do you know if Webclient can do such thing?

Comment: @user3468982 The trick (for both WebClient and HttpRequest/Response) is to persist the CookieCollection across requests. Using Winforms objects from within webforms is bad news.

Comment: I don't really need the cookie, all I need is the value returned in the redirected url after login

Comment: The cookie is how the web server knows that you're logged in. It's what the WebBrowser control does for you that you weren't able to figure out with httpwebreqeust